# BCC email to subscribers

Tags: custom-post-types, email, notifications

I have a custom post type "monthly bulletin" and need to send a blind email to subscribers when a new bulletin is published.

The code below works to send to subscribers, but emails are visible to all.

How do I amend the code to BCC subscribers?

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'send_mails_on_publish', 10, 3 );

function send_mails_on_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{
if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status
    or 'monthlybulletin' !== get_post_type( $post ) )
    return;

$subscribers = get_users( array ( 'role' => 'subscriber' ) );
$emails      = array ();

foreach ( $subscribers as $subscriber )
    $emails[] = $subscriber->user_email;

$body = sprintf( 'Hey there is a new entry!
    See <%s>',
    get_permalink( $post )
);


wp_mail( $emails, 'New entry!', $body );

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the 4th parameter of `wp_mail()` you can extend the header of the Email. So [you can use BCC there](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail#Using_.24headers_To_Set_.22From:.22.2C_.22Cc:.22_and_.22Bcc:.22_Parameters). This should work:

```
<?php
    $bcc = 'Bcc: ';
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $emails as $email ){
        if( $i != 0 )
            $bcc .= ', ';
        $bcc .= $email;
        $i = 1;
    }

    $headers[] = $bcc;
    wp_mail( 'admin@mysite.com', 'New entry!', $body, $headers );
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. Is there a way to mark this question as answered?

Comment: this helps :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers